# Finding Pearson product-moment correlation coefficient

Tags: probability-theory

> Let $A$ be a $3*3$ binary matrix, each element a RV which gets $0$ or
>   $1$ with equal probability. Call a row or column "almost balanced" if
>   it has two $0$s and one $1$. Let $X$ be the number of almost balanced
>   rows and $Y$ the number of almost balanced columns in $A$.
>
> Calculate $\rho_{X,Y}.$

Other then writing the definition of [$\rho$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient) down, I have no idea of how to start solving this problem.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to calculate for each of the $2^9 = 512$ distinct $3 \times 3$ $(0,1)$-matrices in the sample space, the number of matrices with $(X, Y)$ almost balanced rows and columns, for each $X, Y \in \{0, 1, 2, 3\}$.  This gives you the joint distribution for $X$ and $Y$; then it is trivial to compute the correlation from this.

Some hints:

1. It is impossible for $(X, Y) \in \{(2,3), (3,2)\}$.
2. $\Pr[(X,Y) = (x,y)] = \Pr[(X,Y) = (y,x)]$.
3. Try to count the marginal distributions first.

Comment: Thank you. I managed to find everything I need for the formula of the correlation, except $E(XY)$.
On my way there, I need to understand - why, mathematically, is the first hint true? I thought it has to do with the rank of the matrix, but am not sure.

Comment: @Whyka The expectation of the product of $X$ and $Y$ is calculated by taking the product of each ordered pair $(X,Y)$, then taking the weighted sum of each possible product using the probability as weights; i.e., $$\operatorname{E}[XY] = \sum_{k=1}^3 k \Pr[XY = k].$$

Comment: As for the reason why hint 1 is true, reason by contradiction.  Suppose $X = 3$ and $Y = 2$.  Then from the first fact, there must be exactly $3$ ones, one in each row.  From the second fact, exactly two of the columns have exactly $1$ one each.  Where does the third one go?

Comment: @heropop Thanks! I am trying to do what you said in the first comment. First, isn't $k$ supposed to go from 1 to 9? (Your second hint was used here as well). Still, it is not easy to find $P[XY=k]$. I found $P[XY=9]=\frac 6 {512}$, but the rest are still not clear...

Comment: What I got for $E[XY]$ is (after simplification) $P_{X,Y}(1,1)+4P_{X,Y}(1,2)+6P_{X,Y}(1,3)+4P_{X,Y}(2,2)+9P_{X,Y}(3,3)$.

Comment: @Whyka Yes, I incorrectly specified the upper index.  It should be $9$.